# Image 100% width Outlook

Tags: marketing-cloud, email-template, css, html

I'm currently facing an issue that images that are inserting in a marketing cloud custom template are scaling well to 100% at all kind of email clients but Outlook. The max-width is always ignored by outlook, is there a workaround to easily fix max-width for outlook? I've read a workaround to scale the image to the max-width size before uploading it to the marketing cloud.

Has anybody solved that issue before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally outlooks tend to scale the images to its natural width and height if the width is set to 100%. In order to fix this issue I tend to keep the width and height inlined in the image css.

Here are the steps to reproduce:

- Upload an image of any width and set it to the desired width (width less than the actual email table) inlined in the `<img` attribute. The reason why we set fixed width and height to `<img` attribute is because outlook doesn't keep the image size to table width and sets to natural image size.
- Set a class to the `<img` attribute or set it to the `<td>` which is wrapping the `<img` attribute. If you're using the content builder then it will strip out all the elements from `<img` tag that's why it is best to set the class to `<td>`

Here is the sample code:

**1. In the email body**

```
<table class="emailWidthAuto" width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td class="banner" align="center"><img src="http://unsplash.it/g/1200/400?text=BANNER" border="0" alt="Banner"  style="display:block; width: 600px" width="600" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**2. In the email header**

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .emailWidthAuto {
        width: 100% !important;
        height: auto !important;
        min-width: 100% !important;
        max-width: 100% !important;
    }
    .banner img {
        height: auto !important;
        width: 100% !important;
    }
}
```

> Reference post to set this as a content block for users with limited
>   knowledge of html and css **[here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/187940/content-area-for-images-in-outlook/187942?noredirect=1#comment283655_187942)**.

Comment: Hi Brad, thanks! Is there a way to automate this? We  have some users that aren‘t really into HTML & CSS. I mean, we can at least put the css in our email templates header. Put don‘t have an idea on how to automate the image attributes/table.

Comment: @MichaelH I have updated my answer above which includes setting this up in a content builder in sfmc. Please accept and up-vote my answer if found useful. thank you

Answer (score 0):

I am using this with perfect success in Outlook 365 (2022):

```
<img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/1000" width="100%" style="width: 100%;">
```